# Application which will display the current coordinates of the mouse cursor?

Tags: software-recommendation, xorg

I'd like to be able to display the current location of the pointer on the X display. Is there any application which does this?

Comment: I found a solution.

There's a package called xdotool that has an application named getmouselocation.
It works like this:


sconklin@xps-1:~$ xdotool getmouselocation
x:1285 y:10 screen:0

Comment: please write that in an actual answer, once the site allows you to.

Comment: I wrote it up as an answer for you (wiki mode to not take undue rep for it).

Answer (score 41):

There's a package called `xdotool` that has an application named `getmouselocation`, available from ubuntu repositories with `sudo apt-get install xdotool`. Running the command

```
xdotool getmouselocation
```

will output

```
x:1285 y:10 screen:0
```

Comment: Probably "watch xdotool getmouselocation" is what most people are looking for.

Answer (score 14):

1. Install xdotool
2. Open a terminal and paste this:

   ```
   while true; do clear; xdotool getmouselocation; sleep 0.1; done
   ```

Move the cursor over the screen and you will see live coordinates update on terminal.

Comment: or `watch -n 0.1 "xdotool getmouselocation"`

Answer (score 3):

[`xev`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/xev.1.html) from the command line shows this. Try the following.

```
xev
```

Current coordinates are displayed as `root:(<x>,<y>)`.

Comment: It seems to be `xev` only shows the location when the mouse cursor is pointing at the window which `xev` opens.

Comment: Check out updated answer.

Comment: @kcpr, what?  I don't see any `root:(<x>,<y>)` in the terminal window that holds the `xev` data.

Comment: @user1717828, did You try what Ilari Kajaste suggested?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from Xlib import display
import sys

while True:
    c = display.Display().screen().root.query_pointer()._data
    x = c["root_x"]
    y = c["root_y"]

    sys.stdout.write(f'{x:04} {y:04}\r')
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Save it to file `myscript.py`, and launch with `python3 myscript.py`.

Answer (score 0):

Not a native Linux solution, but if you have Wine installed, [Pixie](http://www.nattyware.com/pixie.php) is a free (as in beer) small app that will show you both your cursor's coordinates and the color of the pixel directly underneath it in several formats.